# Run Time Error 9 Subscript out of Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm a bit of a noob to VB for Excel, but I'm hoping to get a lot better in the next few months. Tons of ways it can make my team's job easier. Can someone please help me figure out how to get this macro to run? I've already worked through a few issues but any expertise is welcome.

I'm trying to create a form that people can fill out with Census Data, and then I'll have formulas running off this data in another sheet.

I'm currently getting the highlighted error on the part "Sheets(strName).Select"

```
Sub InputSheet()

Dim sName As String
Dim sStatus As String
Dim sSalary As String
Dim sBonus As String
Dim sPartner As String
Dim sWorkState As String
Dim sBenefitsLevel As String

sName = InputBox("Input Employee Name:", "PROJECT INFORMATION")
sStatus = InputBox("Input FT or PT:", "PROJECT INFORMATION")
sSalary = InputBox("Input Salary:", "PROJECT INFORMATION")
sBonus = InputBox("Input Bonus:", "PROJECT INFORMATION")
sPartner = InputBox("Input Partner Status (Y/N):", "PROJECT INFORMATION")
sWorkState = InputBox("Input Work State:", "PROJECT INFORMATION")
sBenefitsLevel = InputBox("Input Benefits Level:", "PROJECT INFORMATION")


Dim MyNewSheet As Worksheet
Set MyNewSheet = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Dim strName As String
strName = "Project Data "

Sheets(strName).Select
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Employee Name or Title"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Employment Status"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "Salary"

Cells(1, 4).Value = "Bonus"
Cells(1, 5).Value = "Partner Status"
Cells(1, 6).Value = "Work State"
Cells(1, 7).Value = "Benefits Level"
Cells(2, 1).Value = sName
Cells(2, 2).Value = sStatus
Cells(2, 3).Value = sSalary
Cells(2, 4).Value = sBonus
Cells(2, 5).Value = sPartner
Cells(2, 6).Value = sWorkState
Cells(2, 7).Value = sBenefitsLevel
ThisWorkbook.Save

MsgBox "Process is Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: No sheet of the supplied name can be found. I'd suspect the trailing whitespace character in 'Project Data ' ...

Comment: Or, there simply is no sheet with that name.  Developing code involves error handling as well you need to account for the fact a user may have removed or renamed the worksheet what should happen in those cases? do you create a new sheet called that? more than that, what happens when you run the macro twice for the same workbook.  There goes the first round of data...

Answer (score 1):

You have a space at the end of strName - is the tab named "Project Data" or "Project Data "?